# Llenar una tabla de bootstrap con ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo datos de un **ajax** y todo bien solo quisiera saber como indagar dentro del objeto y en mi success llenar una tabla, esto es lo que tengo

```js
// -- /get-owners
function getowners(){
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-owners',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data)=>{
            alert(data);
            $.each(data,(index,item) => {
                alert(index,item);
            });
        }

    });
    //$("#ownerT").load();

};

getowners();



// objeto Json que me devuelve


[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "created_at": "2019-03-21T05:20:44.100Z",
        "username": "xxxx",
        "name": "xxxx",
        "lastnameP": "xxxx",
        "lastnameM": "xxxx",
        "pass": "$2a$10$xvj8YrAT5QP8ezLHEgcAy.Jmslo/x6q/6BjICBtmysfttd3n9Joka",
        "mail": "x@gmail.com",
        "admin": null,
        "user": null,
        "owner": 1,
        "gender": null,
        "datenac": "1965-03-01T06:00:00.000Z",
        "phone": "9611545746",
        "calle": null,
        "colonia": null,
        "estado": null,
        "cp": null,
        "img": '/somewhere/myimage.jpg',
        "id_usercreated": 2,
        "status": null
    }
]
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <h3>Owner de proyecto</h3>
  <div class="top2 table-wrapper-scroll-y">


    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Img</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="ownerT">


      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una manera de llenar la tabla en el caso que nos has enseñado. Si necesitas más campos, etc. Creo que podrás guiarte con esto:

```
function getowners(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-owners',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data)=>{
            alert(data);
            $.each(data,(index,item) => {

                const fila = $('<tr></tr>'); // Creamos la fila

                const img = $('<td></td>').append($('<img class="image">'));

                const name = $('<td></td>').addClass('name');

                const action = $('<td></td>').addClass('action');

                fila.append(img).append(name).append(action); // Preparamos la fila

                data.forEach(dato => { // Iteramos los datos

                  const miFila = fila.clone(); // Clonamos la fila.

                  miFila.find('img').attr('src', dato.img); // Ponemos la imagen

                  miFila.children('.name').html(dato.name); // Ponemos el nombre

                  $('#ownerT').append(miFila); // Pegamos la fila a la tabla

                });
            });
        }

    });
    //$("#ownerT").load();

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una solución más sencilla, escribiendo HTML en JS y con datos interpolados.

Que te sirva

```
function getowners(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get-owners',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) => {

            data.forEach( ( item ) => {
                const row = `<tr>
                    <td><img src="${ item.img }"></td>
                    <td>${ item.name }</td>
                    <td><button>Eliminar</button></td>
                </tr>`;
                $('#ownerT').append( row );
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Buena tarde, quizá te ayude esto:**

```js
//JSON que retorna tu AJAX
var json = [{
    "id": 3,
    "created_at": "2019-03-21T05:20:44.100Z",
    "username": "xxxx",
    "name": "xxxx",
    "lastnameP": "xxxx",
    "lastnameM": "xxxx",
    "pass": "$2a$10$xvj8YrAT5QP8ezLHEgcAy.Jmslo/x6q/6BjICBtmysfttd3n9Joka",
    "mail": "x@gmail.com",
    "admin": null,
    "user": null,
    "owner": 1,
    "gender": null,
    "datenac": "1965-03-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "phone": "9611545746",
    "calle": null,
    "colonia": null,
    "estado": null,
    "cp": null,
    "img": "/somewhere/myimage.jpg",
    "id_usercreated": 2,
    "status": null
  }];

//Código que debes hacer en tu .each() para rellenar tu tabla
$.each(json, (index, item) => {
  var tdData =
    '<tr><td>' + json[index].id + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].created_at + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].username + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].name + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].lastnameP + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].lastnameM + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].pass + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + json[index].mail + '</td></tr>';
  $('#ownerT').append(tdData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Owner de proyecto</h3>


<table class="table table-hover" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">id</th>
      <th scope="col">created_at</th>
      <th scope="col">username</th>
      <th scope="col">name</th>
      <th scope="col">lastnameP</th>
      <th scope="col">lastnameM</th>
      <th scope="col">pass</th>
      <th scope="col">mail</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="ownerT">


  </tbody>
</table>
```